# Formalizing the idea that $\int_{x - \delta/2}^{x + \delta/2}f(u)\,du \approx \delta f(x)$ for small $\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-distributions

I'm trying to formalize a statement provided in the book *Mathematical Statistics and Data Analytics* by John A. Rice (in pg. 48). The statement from the text is as follows:

Let $X$ be a piecewise continuous random variable with real-valued density function $f$. For small $\delta$, if $f$ is continuous at $x$,
$$P\left(x - \frac{\delta}{2} \leq X \leq x + \frac{\delta}{2} \right) = \int_{x - \delta/2}^{x + \delta/2} f(u) \, du \approx \delta f(x) \tag{1}$$
I'm assuming that this can be formalized into the following statement (which I'm aiming to prove):

Let $X$ be a piecewise continuous random variable with real-valued density function $f$. Suppose that $f$ is continuous at $x$. For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$\left| \int_{x - \delta/2}^{x + \delta/2} f(u) \, du - \delta f(x)\right| < \varepsilon \tag{2} $$
Since $f$ is continuous at $x$, I know that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(u) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$ when $u \in (x - \delta/2, x + \delta/2)$. From here, however, I'm stuck, as I can't figure out a way to deal with the $\delta$ term within the inequality in (2). I would appreciate some hints on how to proceed further with my proof, or if the statement I'm trying to prove has a counterexample (and how to properly formalize the original statement (1) in that case).

Comment: Note that $\delta f(x) = \int_{x-\delta/2}^{x+\delta/2} f(x) \, du$.

Comment: This just amounts to the FTC

Comment: This is called Lebesgue differentiation Theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: @LL3.14 OP is assuming $f$ continuous at $x$, so no need to use Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Comment: The right inequality is $$\left|\frac{1}{\delta} \int_{x-\delta/2}^{x+\delta/2}f(u)\,du-f(x)\right|<\epsilon$$ which is just a consequence of definition of continuity of $f$ at $x$. Assuming $\delta<1$ you get the inequality in question by multiplying the above with $\delta$.

Comment: On the other hand if $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $x$ then by mean value theorem for integrals the integral in question equals $\delta f(c) $ for some $c\in (x-\delta/2,x+\delta/2)$ and this is nearly equal to $\delta f(x) $ via continuity.